# How to display div with JavaScript depending on which image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html

I wish to display certain divs inside a main div dependent on which image is clicked. With out any decent knoweldge of Js or Jquery, I fail to do this without some assistance.

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="prod">
    <div id="images">
        <img id="one" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
        <img id="two" src="http://lorempixel.com/201/200/ ">
        <img id="three" src="http://lorempixel.com/203/200/ ">
        <img id="four" src="http://lorempixel.com/204/200/ ">
    </div>
</form>     
<div id="description">
</div>

<div class="one">Brilliant</div>
<div class="two">Super</div>
<div class="tree">Amazing</div>
<div class="four">Excellent</div>
```

If the image which has `id="one"` is clicked, then display `<div class="one">Brilliant</div>` inside of the description div. Then ofcause if the second image is clicked, then display the the 'super' div inside the description div. I'd like to not have the descriptions visible until clicked, and only one div at a time to be shown.

The images are apart of a form because I need to forward the value of the `id` on the images to a variable.

Here is the script that does that.

```
$('#images').delegate('img', 'click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    // Clear formatting
    $('#images img').removeClass('border-highlight');

    // Highlight with coloured border
    $this.addClass('border-highlight');

    // Changes the value of the form field prod to the file name shown in the image.
    $('[name="prod"]').val($this.attr('id').substring($this.attr('id').lastIndexOf('-') + 1));

    //Alert for debugging simplicity
    alert($('[name="prod"]').val());
});
```

Perhaps a function can be implemented into the current script?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLbpJ/1/), and it will all make sense of what I have as a whole currently.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate IDs in your DOM. Use a class instead.

Comment: How silly of me, very good point, thank you, just edited it! :)

Comment: solution with raw javascript [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/NLbpJ/4/)

Comment: @Givi Unfortunately, that is not the result I am looking for, thankyou for your contribution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [fidde](http://jsfiddle.net/dimboiu/NLbpJ/5/)

You just need to add:

```
$('#description').html($('.' + $this.attr('id')).html());
```

At the bottom of your onclick function.

** You have a typo on the 3rd div with text(tree instead of three).

Answer (score 1):

You can make it bit simple by adding the `divs` for description in `div` as I see no need to put the divs for description outside the `description` div and later adding it. You will need to `hide` all the divs we have in description `div` and `show` the one that is related to `img` being clicked.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NLbpJ/3/)**

*Html*

```
<input type="hidden" name="prod">
<div id="images">
    <img id="imgone" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
    <img id="imgtwo" src="http://lorempixel.com/201/200" />
    <img id="imgthree" src="http://lorempixel.com/203/200" />
    <img id="imgfour" src="http://lorempixel.com/204/200" />
</div>
<div id="description">
    <div id="one">Brilliant</div>
    <div id="two">Super</div>
    <div id="three">Amazing</div>
    <div id="four">Excellent</div>
</div>
```

*Javascript*

```
$('#images').delegate('img', 'click', function () {
    $('#description div').hide();
    $('#' + this.id.replace('img', '')).show();
});
```

Comment: This answer I find correct also, however, I accepted Eugen's answer as his version kept my current script that was vital for what I needed.